# How to add significance weighting in user based collaborative filtering

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system, information-retrieval, weight-initialization

I have been learning about recommender systems these past days. More specifically about the collaborative filtering. While exploring I found that it can be useful to use "significance weighting" in the prediction formula to give more weight to users that have more co-rated items.
The formula they use for this significance weighting is the following:
[image]

But I don't really get how they find the β. They say it can be done by cross-validation, but I don't really understand what that mean. Can someone help me out?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is generally done thanks to many trials and improvements.

After splitting into train and test data, they try out different values of beta, training the model on the training data using each value, and then evaluating the model on the test data.

The value of beta that gives the best performance is then chosen as the final value for the model.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer! Is there any specific range of numbers/values between which I should search for the value of β?

Comment: It depends on the weighting techniques. If you have no idea, you could start with distant values (like: 0.01, 0.9, and 5), and then improve by dichotomy. https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-01891-6_7

Comment: Does it answer your question? If not, please let me know to provide additional information.